# middle div take up remaining space?

Tags: css, html

I have three `div`s,

```
divl : 7px width
divr: 7px width
divm: unknown
```

What I want to do is:

- Have `divl` at the very left of the parent `div`,
- `divr` at the very right of the parent `div`.
- `divm` in between those two `div`s and span the remaining space.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you'll want to use what was linked

> Blockquote http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Or see http://www.webreference.com/authoring/style/sheets/css_mastery2/index.html (and the subsequent pages)
I came up with the following but you'll probably end up with an overlap on content from the left and middle divs (you could try adding z-index to the middle div as well, that may help.)

```
   <html> 
    <style type="text/css">
      #divl { width: 7px; float: left; height: 100px; }
      #divm { width: 100%; height: 100px; margin: 0 -7px; float: left; }
      #divr { width: 7px; height: 100px; float: left; }
    </style>
      <body>
        <div id="divl"></div>
        <div id="divm"></div>
        <div id="divr"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```