# Variable width for the center div with fixed left & right div having transparent rounded corners images

Tags: css, transparency, html, rounded-corners

I'm trying to display

- a variable width popup
- that will have rounded corners with transparent edges to match the background color.

First I thought it was a simple rounded corner markup, but then the problem was with transparent background for the radius and the variable width of the popup.

```
<css>
    .c-dialog-rc-tl, .c-dialog-rc-tc, .c-dialog-rc-tr,
    .c-dialog-rc-bl, .c-dialog-rc-bc, .c-dialog-rc-br {
        background-color: none;
        height: 10px;
    }
    .c-dialog-rc-tl, .c-dialog-rc-bl { 
        float:left;
        width:20px;
    }
    .c-dialog-rc-tl {
        background-position: 0 -30px;
        z-index:1005;
        position:absolute;
    }
    .c-dialog-rc-bl {
        background-position: 0 -43px;
        z-index:1004;
        position:absolute;
    }
</css>

<div class="c-dialog-rc-top">
    <div class="c-dialog-image c-dialog-rc-tl"></div>
    <div class="c-dialog-image c-dialog-rc-tc"></div>
    <div class="c-dialog-image c-dialog-rc-tr"></div>
</div>
```

I tried the replies of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414685/middle-div-take-up-remaining-space) but didn't work.
Please see the code at [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cAQF8/).

I'll try to provide as much as information if the question is not clear but please don't downvote or delete the question.

Has anybody solved this kind of problem, or know a better div layout or a css that will render such a requirement ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No comments ? nobody ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order of the rounded corners worked and with a little bit of change in css.

```
<div class="c-dialog-rc-top">
    <div class="c-dialog-image c-dialog-rc-tl"></div>
    <div class="c-dialog-image c-dialog-rc-tr"></div>
    <div class="c-dialog-image c-dialog-rc-tc"></div>
</div>
<style>
    /* explaining here in short, please refer fiddle for full css */
    .c-dialog-rc-tl {float:left;}
    .c-dialog-rc-tr {float:right;}
    .c-dialog-rc-tc {overflow:auto}
</style>
```

Link to updated fiddle  : http://fiddle.jshell.net/zMtg7/5/